# What is the difference between $(S^{2}\times S^{1})\# (S^{2}\times S^{1})\# (S^{2}\times S^{1})$ and $ S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, low-dimensional-topology, continuous-homomorphisms

What is the difference between $(S^{2}\times S^{1})\# (S^{2}\times S^{1})\# (S^{2}\times S^{1})$ and $S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}$.

Where their homology groups are:
If $\;\;\;\;(S^{2}\times S^{1})\# (S^{2}\times S^{1})\# (S^{2}\times S^{1})=3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}):$

$H_0(3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}))=H_3(3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}))=\mathbb{Z}$

$H_1(3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}))=H_2(3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}))=\mathbb{Z}^3$

and for $S^{1}\times S^{1}\times S^{1}=T^3$:

$H_0(T^3)=H_3(T^3)=\mathbb{Z}$

$H_1(T^3)=H_2(T^3)=\mathbb{Z}^3$

Thus,    $\;\;\;\;\; H_0(T^3)=H_3(T^3)=H_0(3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}))=H_3(3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}))=\mathbb{Z}$,
 $H_1(T^3)=H_2(T^3)=H_1(3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}))=H_2(3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}))=\mathbb{Z}^3$

and
 $\;\;\;\;\; H_n(T^3)=H_n(3-(S^{2}\times S^{1}))=\mathbb{Z}=0,\;\;\;\forall n>3$

I have a doubt, these two 3 varieties are homeomorphic?   If the answer is not,  what is the difference?

thanks for the answer.

Comment: Their fundamental groups are different.

Comment: More to the point, $H_1$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1$. Connected sums and products map to free products and direct products, respectively, under $\pi_1$ (under some additional assumptions that hold here); passing to $H_1$ reduces the free products to direct products, and you lose that distinction.

Answer (score 2):

For $M,N$ with dimension $n>2$ the connected sum $M\# N$ has fundamental group $\pi_1(M\# N) \approx \pi_1(M) * \pi_1(N)$ as the boundary of the $n$-ball used for identification is simply connected. Thus $\pi_1(3-(S^2 \times S^1)) \approx \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$ yet $\pi_1(T^3) \approx \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. So we conclude the two spaces are not homotopic.

Comment: can you clarify what is 3−(^2×^1)?

Comment: This was the notation established in the question, the connect sum in question.